# WPF: Having multiple custom control be notified when a property change

Tags: wpf, properties, notifications

We have a specific case of having various type of custom controls that must react differently when a property change.

What would be the best way to handle this in WPF and if you have a quick tutorial, it would be appreciated.

Thx

Comment: Some more detail about the problem set may be helpful; because if you already have varying types of custom controls defined which you want to react differently against a given property then you should be set...not sure I see the problem...

Comment: Is your situation that you have a view model that exposes a property, and when that property changes, the custom controls in the view need to react/update their individual views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with `INotifyPropertyChanged` ? Each control can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event and react to it in its own specific way

Comment: I agree, use the INotifyPropertyChanged within your class & the corresponding properties that will be bound.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

I have created my data object which inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged (based from many sample I saw on the web.

But at this time, I am still puzzle of how in my custom control objects I register to the data object to be notified when the property change and my custom code being executed.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just subscribe to the event: `yourObject.PropertyChanged += YourEventHandler`

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanaiton, I am now up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, use the INotifiyPropertyChanged interface on the object you are binding all of the different UI components to. here is msdn's example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Enjoy!